# in python 3.6.3, what is wrong with this program? It says invalid syntax on the line with: if Ui3 == "no":

Tags: python, python-3.x

sorry if the formatting is a little screwy. first question asked on here.

```
from random import randint
num=randint(1,9)  #generates random number

print("welcome to the guessing game! the number is between 1 and 9.")

tries=0
player_input=int(input("enter your guess"))
while num != player_input:

    if player_input == " ":
        print("Invalid entry.")
        player_input=int(input("please entera valid number between 1 and 9"))

    if player_input < num:
        tries = tries +1
        print("too low")
        print(" ")
        player_input=int(input("guess again "))

    if player_input > num:
        tries = tries +1
        print("too high!")
        print(" ")
        player_input = int(input("guess again "))

    if player_input == num:
        tries = tries +1
        print("You Got It!!")
        print(" ")
        print("you have tried",tries,"times")
        next


newg=("yes") # = new game
endg=("no")  # = stop game
print("To start a new game enter ", newg, ". Or to stop the game, enter ", endg)




user=(input("Y/N") 


# the syntax error shows up here. i have tries different variable instead of ui3 such as new_game_a, ng, U_I, ui, etc.i have fixed that problem, but now it is the " : " at the end of the line. i tried many variations in spacing. but still no lee-way with error.

if user == "no":
    print("close window")

else user == "yes":
    tries=0
    player_input=int(input("enter your guess"))


    while num != player_input:

        if player_input == " ":
            print("Invalid entry.")
            player_input=int(input("please enter  valid number between 1 and 9"))

        if player_input < num:
            tries = tries +1
            print("too low")
            print(" ")
            player_input=int(input("guess again "))

        if player_input > num:
            tries = tries +1
            print("too high!")
            print(" ")
            player_input = int(input("guess again "))

        if player_input == num:
            tries = tries +1
            print("You Got It!!")
            print(" ")
        print("you have tried",tries,"times")
```

PLEASE help me if possible, thanks.
[an example of the error message!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rAG6.png)

Comment: You have an extra open ( on the previous line.

Comment: `user=(input("Y/N")` lacks a second closing parentheses.

Comment: The code runs once you add the second parenthesis for me not sure if it does what you want exactly

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe I'm not sure how that'd be possible, as `else user == "yes":` is not proper syntax (at least in Python 3.x)

Comment: Error seems to be in If-Else statement.
if user == "no":
    print("close window")
elif user == "yes":

Comment: I tried the top code which is where I thought he was having the problem didn't check the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's most likely more than this (the extra closing parentheses required which may have just been a typo), but I see that your syntax is incorrect.

```
else user == "yes":
```

Should be replaced with:

```
elif user == "yes":
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing `)` on the line defining `user` and `else` doesn't take another condition:

```
user=(input("Y/N"))
if user == "no":
    print("close window")

else:
    tries=0
    player_input=int(input("enter your guess"))
```